# How can I redirect users to the poll page after they vote?

Tags: redirect, drupal-6

How can I redirect the user to the *same poll page* instead of the homepage after voting? I'm unable find which function to override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom module that attach a new submission handler to the form shown to vote a pool, and change the redirection using `$form_state['redirect'] = '/node/' . $nid`, when $nid is the node ID of the node being shown.